# How to run a standalone DNSSEC root zone?

Tags: testing, networking, dns, bind, dnssec

I got this white lab.  It has its own top-level domain (TLD) name `whitelab.` and ISC Bind9 9.15 is used.

This makes it possible to rollout many network testing scenarios in-house.

How does one DNSSEC-sign this custom-made TLD such that it not only works in providing secured DNS lookup from within Bind `whitelab` view/network, but reverts to the ISC Root Key when DNSSEC-resolving domain name(s) outside the white lab?  Obviously ICANN won't add this `whitelab` TLD for the entire world to use as well (nor would we want to).

Some basic ISC Bind9 v9.15 settings:

```
options {
    ...
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes; //// not 'auto', nor 'no'.
    ...
    };

view whitelab {
    ...
    trusted-keys {
        whitelab. 257 3 14 "<key-value>";
        };
    ...
    };
```

Rolling out the above configuration in a non-Internet (local/whitelab) Bind view resulted in breaking the DNSSEC for Internet-wide Bind view.

Keys were created by doing:

```
dnssec-keygen -v3 -G  -n ZONE  -a ECDSAP384SHA384 whitelab.
dnssec-keygen -v3 -G  -n ZONE  -a ECDSAP384SHA384 168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

Is this 'trusted-keys' approach the correct one?

Comment: Your question is not about programming so offtopic here. Maybe better on [su] of [sf]. You may want however to go deeper on "resulted in breaking the DNSSEC for Internet-wide Bind view." by providing specific traces of dig outputs... Also maybe try with other vrsions, bind 9.15 is EOL now. Also based on https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01310 `trusted-keys` is replaced by `dnssec-keys` and `static-key`. 9.16 notes also says: "Improved DNSSEC trust anchor configuration using the trust-anchors
statement, permitting configuration of trust anchors in DS as well as
DNSKEY format."

Comment: How do I transfer the question over to the correct forum?

Comment: It seems too old to migrate, so you need to create a new question in the forum where you think it is more appropriate and then close this one. You have some ideas to dig into in my previous comment